# "apt-get install grub" wants to install packages although the GRUB bootmenu works?

Tags: grub2, package-management, grub-legacy

Recently I made a fresh install of Ubuntu, and through some error, became very frustrated. Grub and 15.04 just don't seem to work well together. However, that is not exactly my question. I made the install finally, and when I booted, the grub menu obviously came up, but then when I got into my terminal to install some proprietary drivers, I did `sudo apt-get install grub` just to make sure everything was good. Instead of telling me that Grub was already installed it said 6 new packages would be installed. So here's the question. If the grub menu came up, and grub apparently wasn't installed, which side is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of the package `grub` (GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)) would not only install a deprecated version, but also remove the correct version.

You can see this in the sample output

```
% sudo -s apt-get install grub
[sudo] password for aboettger: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  grub-legacy-doc mdadm
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub2-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 913 kB of archives.
After this operation, 391 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Therefore, do nothing **=)**

GRand Unified Bootloader, Version 2 is installed and all is well if you have **not** pressed <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install grub` is a wrong command to run.

It installs legacy version of grub and removes `grub-pc` or `grub-efi`.

You can check `/var/log/apt/history.log` and revert these changes.